# Issue with payments being totaled instead of listed

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write a sql-server query that generates a report and lists various financials for an account. It should list all payments made in a period and then sum those payments and list the total amount paid for the period. As of now, it is just listing the sum of the total payments in a period for every payment made instead of each individual payment.
Query :

```
SELECT tbl1.fstrAccountID,
       tbl1.flngAccountKey,
       tbl1.fstrName,
       CASE tbl1.fblnEstimate WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS fstrEstimate,
       tbl1.fdtmFilingPeriod,
       tbl1.fcurOil,
       tbl1.fcurOilExp,
       tbl1.fcurNetOil,
       tbl1.fcurNaturalGas,
       tbl1.fcurNaturalGasExp,
       tbl1.fcurNetNaturalGas,
       tbl1.fcurCoalbedMethane,
       tbl1.fcurCoalbedMethaneExp,
       tbl1.fcurNetCoalbedMethane,
       tbl1.fcurSandOrGravel,
       tbl1.fcurLimestoneSandstone,
       tbl1.fcurOtherNaturalResource,
       tbl1.fcurNatGasTransportAllowance,
       tbl1.flngNatGasMCFs,
       tbl1.fcurOilTransportAllowance,
       tbl1.flngOilBarrels,
       tbl1.flngMidVolNatGasBarrels,
       tbl1.fcurMidVolNatGasTransportAllowance,
       tbl1.flngMidVolOilMCFs,
       tbl1.fcurMidVolOilTransportAllowance,
       tbl1.fcurOtherTransportAllowance,
       tbl1.fcurTotalTax,
       tbl1.fcurEstCredit + ISNULL(tbl2.fcurTotalCredit, 0) AS fcurCredits,
       tbl1.fcurNetTax,
       tbl1.fcurPNI,
       CASE tbl1.fblnEstimate
           WHEN 0 THEN tbl1.fcurPeriodCredit
           ELSE ISNULL(tbl3.fcurEstPayments, 0)
       END AS fcurPayments,
       ISNULL(tbl3.fdtmAllocated, @pdtmHighDate) AS fdtmAllocationDate,
       (ISNULL(tbl4.fcurPeriodDestJVs, 0) + ISNULL(tbl5.fcurPeriodSourceJVs, 0)) * -1 AS fcurPeriodJVs
FROM (SELECT tblSev.*,
             ISNULL(tblNgd.fcurTransportAllowance, 0) AS fcurNatGasTransportAllowance,
             ISNULL(tblNgd.flngMCFs, 0) AS flngNatGasMCFs,
             ISNULL(tblOd.fcurTransportAllowance, 0) AS fcurOilTransportAllowance,
             ISNULL(tblOd.flngBarrels, 0) AS flngOilBarrels,
             ISNULL(tblMg.flngMcfsBarrels, 0) AS flngMidVolNatGasBarrels,
             ISNULL(tblMg.fcurTransportAllowance, 0) AS fcurMidVolNatGasTransportAllowance,
             ISNULL(tblMo.flngMcfsBarrels, 0) AS flngMidVolOilMCFs,
             ISNULL(tblMo.fcurTransportAllowance, 0) AS fcurMidVolOilTransportAllowance,
             ISNULL(tblSo.fcurTransportAllowance, 0) AS fcurOtherTransportAllowance
      FROM (SELECT rs.fblnEstimate,
                   ai.flngAccountKey,
                   rsd.flngDocKey,
                   ai.fstrFormattedID AS fstrAccountID,
                   ai.fstrListFormatName AS fstrName,
                   r.fdtmFilingPeriod,
                   SUM(rsd.fcurGrsValOil) AS fcurOil,
                   SUM(rsd.fcurExemptionOil) AS fcurOilExp,
                   SUM(rsd.fcurTxblOil) AS fcurNetOil,
                   SUM(rsd.fcurGrsValNatGas) AS fcurNaturalGas,
                   SUM(rsd.fcurExemptionNatGas) AS fcurNaturalGasExp,
                   SUM(rsd.fcurTxblNatGas) AS fcurNetNaturalGas,
                   SUM(rsd.fcurGrsValMethane) AS fcurCoalbedMethane,
                   SUM(rsd.fcurExemptionMethane) AS fcurCoalbedMethaneExp,
                   SUM(rsd.fcurTxblMethane) AS fcurNetCoalbedMethane,
                   SUM(rsd.fcurTxblSand) AS fcurSandOrGravel,
                   SUM(rsd.fcurTxblLime) AS fcurLimestoneSandstone,
                   SUM(rsd.fcurTxblOther) AS fcurOtherNaturalResource,
                   SUM(rsd.fcurTaxDueOil) + SUM(rsd.fcurTaxDueNatGas) + SUM(rsd.fcurTaxDueMethane) + SUM(rsd.fcurTaxDueSand) + SUM(rsd.fcurTaxDueLime) + SUM(rsd.fcurTaxDueOther) AS fcurTotalTax,
                   CASE rs.fblnEstimate WHEN 1 THEN wr.fcurCredit ELSE 0 END AS fcurEstCredit,
                   wr.fcurTaxDue AS fcurNetTax,
                   p.FCURINTEREST + p.fcurPenalty AS fcurPNI,
                   ABS(p.fcurCredit) AS fcurPeriodCredit
            FROM tblWV_ReturnSEVDelta rsd,
                 tblWV_ReturnSEV rs,
                 tblWV_ReturnInfo ri,
                 tblWV_Return wr,
                 tblReturn r,
                 tblAccountInfo ai,
                 tblPeriod p
            WHERE rsd.flngDocKey = ri.flngDocKey
              AND rsd.flngDocKey = rs.flngDocKey
              AND rsd.flngDocKey = wr.flngDocKey
              AND wr.flngVerLast = 0
              AND ri.flngReturnKey = r.flngReturnKey
              AND r.flngVer = 0
              AND r.fdtmFilingPeriod >= @pdtmDateFrom
              AND r.fdtmFilingPeriod <= @pdtmDateTo
              AND r.flngAccountKey = ai.flngAccountKey
              AND ai.flngAccountKey = p.FLNGACCOUNTKEY
              AND r.fdtmFilingPeriod = p.FDTMFILINGPERIOD
              AND p.FLNGVER = 0
              AND p.fblnActive = 1
            GROUP BY rsd.flngDocKey,
                     ai.flngAccountKey,
                     ai.fstrFormattedID,
                     ai.fstrListFormatName,
                     r.fdtmFilingPeriod,
                     rs.fblnEstimate,
                     wr.fcurCredit,
                     wr.fcurTaxDue,
                     p.FCURINTEREST,
                     p.fcurPenalty,
                     p.fcurCredit) tblSev
          LEFT JOIN (SELECT so.flngDocKey,
                            SUM(so.fcurTransportAllowance) AS fcurTransportAllowance
                     FROM tblWV_ReturnSEVOtherDelta so
                     WHERE so.fcurTransportAllowance > 0
                     GROUP BY so.flngDocKey) tblSo ON tblSev.flngDocKey = tblSo.flngDocKey
          LEFT JOIN (SELECT ngd.flngDocKey,
                            SUM(ngd.fcurTransportAllowance) AS fcurTransportAllowance,
                            SUM(ngd.flngMCFs) AS flngMCFs
                     FROM tblWV_ReturnSEVNaturalGasDelta ngd
                     WHERE ( ngd.fcurTransportAllowance > 0
                          OR ngd.flngMCFs > 0)
                     GROUP BY ngd.flngDocKey) tblNgd ON tblSev.flngDocKey = tblNgd.flngDocKey
          LEFT JOIN (SELECT od.flngDocKey,
                            SUM(od.fcurTransportAllowance) AS fcurTransportAllowance,
                            SUM(od.flngBarrels) AS flngBarrels
                     FROM tblWV_ReturnSEVOilDelta od
                     WHERE ( od.fcurTransportAllowance > 0
                          OR od.flngBarrels > 0)
                     GROUP BY od.flngDocKey) tblOd ON tblSev.flngDocKey = tblOd.flngDocKey
          LEFT JOIN (SELECT mg.flngDocKey,
                            SUM(mg.fcurTransportAllowance) AS fcurTransportAllowance,
                            SUM(mg.flngMcfsBarrels) AS flngMcfsBarrels
                     FROM tblWV_ReturnSEVMidVolumeDelta mg
                     WHERE mg.fstrType = 'NATGAS'
                       AND ( mg.fcurTransportAllowance > 0
                          OR mg.flngMcfsBarrels > 0)
                     GROUP BY mg.flngDocKey) tblMg ON tblSev.flngDocKey = tblMg.flngDocKey
          LEFT JOIN (SELECT mo.flngDocKey,
                            SUM(mo.fcurTransportAllowance) AS fcurTransportAllowance,
                            SUM(mo.flngMcfsBarrels) AS flngMcfsBarrels
                     FROM tblWV_ReturnSEVMidVolumeDelta mo
                     WHERE mo.fstrType = 'OIL'
                       AND ( mo.fcurTransportAllowance > 0
                          OR mo.flngMcfsBarrels > 0)
                     GROUP BY mo.flngDocKey) tblMo ON tblSev.flngDocKey = tblMo.flngDocKey) tbl1
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT tc.flngDocKey,
                      tc.fcurTotalCredit
               FROM tblWV_ReturnSEVDelta rsd,
                    tblWV_ReturnSEV rs,
                    tblWV_ReturnScheduleTC tc,
                    tblWV_ReturnInfo ri,
                    tblWV_Return wr,
                    tblReturn r
               WHERE rsd.flngDocKey = ri.flngDocKey
                 AND rsd.flngDocKey = tc.flngDocKey
                 AND tc.flngVerLast = 0
                 AND rsd.flngDocKey = rs.flngDocKey
                 AND rsd.flngDocKey = wr.flngDocKey
                 AND wr.flngVerLast = 0
                 AND ri.flngReturnKey = r.flngReturnKey
                 AND r.flngVer = 0
                 AND r.fblnInError = 0
                 AND r.fdtmFilingPeriod >= @pdtmDateFrom
                 AND r.fdtmFilingPeriod <= @pdtmDateTo
               GROUP BY tc.flngDocKey,
                        tc.fcurTotalCredit) tbl2 ON tbl1.flngDocKey = tbl2.flngDocKey
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT a.FLNGACCOUNTKEY,
                      a.FDTMFILINGPERIOD,
                      CONVERT(date, a.FDTMALLOCATED) AS fdtmAllocated,
                      SUM(a.FCURAMOUNT) AS fcurEstPayments
               FROM tblALLOCATION a
               WHERE a.fdtmFilingPeriod >= @pdtmDateFrom
                 AND a.fdtmFilingPeriod <= @pdtmDateTo
                 AND a.fdtmReversed = @pdtmHighDate
               GROUP BY a.FLNGACCOUNTKEY,
                        a.FDTMFILINGPERIOD,
                        CONVERT(date, a.FDTMALLOCATED)) tbl3 ON tbl1.flngAccountKey = tbl3.FLNGACCOUNTKEY
                                                            AND tbl1.fdtmFilingPeriod = tbl3.FDTMFILINGPERIOD
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT jvp.flngAccountKey,
                      jvp.fdtmFilingPeriod,
                      SUM(jvp.fcurDestAmount) AS fcurPeriodDestJVs
               FROM tblRATxnJVDetailPostedAll jvp
               WHERE jvp.fdtmFilingPeriod >= @pdtmDateFrom
                 AND jvp.fdtmFilingPeriod <= @pdtmDateTo
                 AND jvp.fstrRevenueGroup = 'SEV'
                 AND jvp.fstrDestRAType <> 'REVCRD'
                 AND jvp.fstrDestRAType IN ('SEVOIL', 'SEVGAS', 'SEVMTH')
               GROUP BY jvp.flngAccountKey,
                        jvp.fdtmFilingPeriod) tbl4 ON tbl1.flngAccountKey = tbl4.flngAccountKey
                                                  AND tbl1.fdtmFilingPeriod = tbl4.fdtmFilingPeriod
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT jvp.flngAccountKey,
                      jvp.fdtmFilingPeriod,
                      SUM(jvp.fcurSourceAmount) AS fcurPeriodSourceJVs
               FROM tblRATxnJVDetailPostedAll jvp
               WHERE jvp.fdtmFilingPeriod >= @pdtmDateFrom
                 AND jvp.fdtmFilingPeriod <= @pdtmDateTo
                 AND jvp.fstrRevenueGroup = 'SEV'
                 AND jvp.fstrDestRAType <> 'REVCRD'
                 AND jvp.fstrSourceRAType IN ('SEVOIL', 'SEVGAS', 'SEVMTH')
               GROUP BY jvp.flngAccountKey,
                        jvp.fdtmFilingPeriod) tbl5 ON tbl1.flngAccountKey = tbl5.flngAccountKey
                                                  AND tbl1.fdtmFilingPeriod = tbl5.fdtmFilingPeriod
ORDER BY fstrAccountID,
         fdtmFilingPeriod;
```

Sample Data:

Payments:

- 182.84
- 57.59
- 38.31

Table Data:

[Table data frm tblAllocation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJXmM.png)

Results (of payment section) :

| Period | Payments |
| --- | --- |
| 12-31-2020 | 285.56 |
|  | 285.56 |
|  | 285.56 |
| Total | 285.56 |

Desired Results:

| Period | Payments |
| --- | --- |
| 12-31-2020 | 182.84 |
|  | 57.59 |
|  | 38.31 |
| Total | 285.56 |

Results should list the 3 payments made and then total the payments in the last row.

Comment: Please add representative sample data and desired outcome as text.

Comment: If you want to aggregate and have a grand total, why not use `ROLLUP` or `GROUPING SETS`?

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) It's 2023; the ANSI-92 JOIN syntax has been around for *over **30 years*** now. Why do you use it for the derived table, but not against the tables? You clearly know the syntax exists, so why occasion slip back into the 1980's?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for windowed functions!

Consider the following (using my RandomSales database, since you didn't provide any DDL/DML).

```
SELECT i.InvoiceID, i.CustomerID, i.EmployeeID, i.storeID, i.InvoiceDateTimeUTC, ii.Price, ii.Quantity, ii.Price * ii.Quantity AS ItemTotal, 
       SUM(ii.Price * ii.Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY i.InvoiceID) AS InvoiceTotal,
       SUM(ii.Price * ii.Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(I.InvoiceDateTimeUTC AS DATE)) AS DailyInvoiceTotal
  FROM dbo.Invoices i
    INNER JOIN dbo.InvoiceItems ii
      ON i.InvoiceID = ii.InvoiceID;
```

| InvoiceID | CustomerID | EmployeeID | storeID | InvoiceDateTimeUTC | Price | Quantity | ItemTotal | InvoiceTotal | DailyInvoiceTotal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 88622 | 321 | 89 | 34 | 2021-05-22 19:17:15.9633333 | 12.00 | 1 | 12.00 | 52.00 | 4464.40 |
| 88622 | 321 | 89 | 34 | 2021-05-22 19:17:15.9633333 | 9.00 | 2 | 18.00 | 52.00 | 4464.40 |
| 88622 | 321 | 89 | 34 | 2021-05-22 19:17:15.9633333 | 6.00 | 2 | 12.00 | 52.00 | 4464.40 |
| 88622 | 321 | 89 | 34 | 2021-05-22 19:17:15.9633333 | 10.00 | 1 | 10.00 | 52.00 | 4464.40 |
| 1124 | 507 | 2 | 57 | 2021-05-23 19:17:15.9633333 | 6.90 | 1 | 6.90 | 49.80 | 11051.30 |
| 1124 | 507 | 2 | 57 | 2021-05-23 19:17:15.9633333 | 12.00 | 2 | 24.00 | 49.80 | 11051.30 |
| 1124 | 507 | 2 | 57 | 2021-05-23 19:17:15.9633333 | 6.90 | 1 | 6.90 | 49.80 | 11051.30 |
| 1124 | 507 | 2 | 57 | 2021-05-23 19:17:15.9633333 | 12.00 | 1 | 12.00 | 49.80 | 11051.30 |

Here we're using windowed version of `SUM` to aggregate over the whole invoice and the whole day. The results are the last invoice of one day, and the first invoice of the following day for brevity. You can also provide the optional  `ORDER` with your windowed functions, which can be useful for running totals and the like.

In your case, a windowed `SUM` should provide what you're looking for.

Comment: This looks like it would work, I am going to implement and see how it works. I need all the payments in a period listed and then summed, would this count the amount of payments made or the monetary amount of the payment?

Comment: It will aggregate based on what you provide. If you'd rather, you could use `COUNT` instead of `SUM`.